# Draw a line that encloses some objects in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Given an array of circles, I want to draw a line that tightly encloses the circles. Since a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

The code to produce the array of circles is as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={draw=LimeGreen, fill=LimeGreen!15,
    circle, inner sep=.1111em, minimum size=1.2222em},
   thick]

  \node [] (01) at (0,0) {1};
  \node [left] (02) at (01.west) {};
  \node [left] (03) at (02.west) {};
  \node [left] (04) at (03.west) {};

  \node [above] (05) at (01.north) {};
  \node [above] (06) at (02.north) {};
  \node [above] (07) at (03.north) {3};
  \node [above] (08) at (04.north) {};

  \node [below] (09) at (01.south) {};
  \node [below] (10) at (02.south) {};
  \node [below] (11) at (03.south) {};
  \node [below] (12) at (04.south) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `fit` library to make a node and then draw along three of its sides?

Comment: Or just use a ‘local bounding box’ and dial the radius of the rounded corners to be the one of the circles, and then do as @cfr suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possible way, very much as @cfr suggests but with a `local bounding box` instead of `fit`.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={draw=LimeGreen, fill=LimeGreen!15,
    circle, inner sep=.1111em, minimum size=1.2222em},
   thick]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=circs]
  \node [] (01) at (0,0) {1};
  \node [left] (02) at (01.west) {};
  \node [left] (03) at (02.west) {};
  \node [left] (04) at (03.west) {};

  \node [above] (05) at (01.north) {};
  \node [above] (06) at (02.north) {};
  \node [above] (07) at (03.north) {3};
  \node [above] (08) at (04.north) {};

  \node [below] (09) at (01.south) {};
  \node [below] (10) at (02.south) {};
  \node [below] (11) at (03.south) {};
  \node [below] (12) at (04.south) {};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[rounded corners={(1.2222em+2*\pgflinewidth)/2}] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]circs.north west) 
  |- ([yshift=-\pgflinewidth]circs.south) -| ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]circs.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: you'd be way better off with a `matrix of nodes` IMHO.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,inner sep=0pt,outer
  sep=\pgflinewidth/2,
  cells={nodes={draw=LimeGreen, fill=LimeGreen!15,execute at begin
  node=\vphantom{1},
    circle, inner sep=.1111em, minimum size=1.2222em}}] (circs)
    { & 3 & & \\
      &   & & 1 \\
      & & & \\};
  \draw[rounded corners={(1.2222em+2*\pgflinewidth)/2}] (circs.north west) 
  |- (circs.south) -| (circs.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with an arbitrary line width (to be set with `my line width/.initial=...`.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,my line width/.initial=1.5pt]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,inner sep=0pt,outer
  sep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my line width}/2,
  cells={nodes={draw=LimeGreen, fill=LimeGreen!15,execute at begin
  node=\vphantom{1},
    circle, inner sep=.1111em, minimum size=1.2222em}}] (circs)
    { & 3 & & \\
      &   & & 1 \\
      & & & \\};
  \draw[line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my line width},rounded corners={(1.2222em+0.8pt+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my line width})/2}] (circs.north west) 
  |- (circs.south) -| (circs.north east) ;
  % the line width of thick is 0.8pt
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot! Regarding the matrix-based solution: Why exactly do we need this `execute at begin node=\vphantom{1}`? I don't understand why omitting it breaks the graphic...

Comment: @user1494080 It is just a trick to fill the circles with *something* that has the same height as the circles that have really a content, but no width, such that the shifts you mention do not occur. The shifts are because if there is no content the baseline of the circles moves,  and therefore they get vertically displaced.

Comment: Sounds logical. Another follow-up question: If I want to give the enclosing line a larger line width, then I can't simply write `\pgflinewidth`, because that refers to enclosing line width, not the lw of the circles. Is there any elegant possibility to reference the circle's lw from within the options of the enclosing line?

Comment: @user1494080 I added something that allows you to adjust the line widths. In the `matrix` code, in `rounded corners={(1.2222em+2*\pgflinewidth)/2}` the term `2*\pgflinewidth` may be thought of as `line width of the circles + line width of the border`, which coincide in the upper two examples.